# Echo substring problem in parantheses with html

Tags: php

```
<?php 
  echo '                                                        <tr>
                                                                <td>John Doe</td>
                                                                <td>34</td>
                                                                <td>44</td>
                                                                <td>' .$ks1. '</td>
                                                                <td>' .$ks1. '</td>
                                                                <td>' . ($ks2 - $ks1) . '</td>
                                                                <td><div class="progress progress-lg">
    <div class="progress-bar" data-progress="' . ($ks1*100 / $ks2) . '"></div>
</div></td>'; ?>
```

When I run this page, progress bar shows 75.75757575757. I want to get first 4 digit.
I try to add substr but it gives error.

```
<div class="progress-bar" data-progress="'substr(. ($ks2*100 / $ks1) .,1,4);'"></div>
</div></td>'; ?>
```

How can i fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [round()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) in this case:

```
<?php 
  echo '<tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>' .$ks1. '</td>
        <td>' .$ks1. '</td>
        <td>' . ($ks2 - $ks1) . '</td>
        <td><div class="progress progress-lg">
                <div class="progress-bar" data-progress="' . round(($ks1 * 100 / $ks2), 2) . '"></div>
            </div></td>'; 
?>
```

This will return 75.76 because of the rounding. If you still want 75.75 you can use `substr()`, but that will only work if the number is between 10 and 99 whereas `round()` will always return 2 decimals (at most).